# Python\Opera incognito\ private mode

Tags: python, browser, incognito-mode

I can not seem to find any documentation on how to open Opera in incognito mode

Could anyone help me with this please?

this is the part of code i need to include to open opera , but i have no idea how to inlcude the incognito mode

```
`import os
 import webbrowser


os.startfile(C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\launcher.exe)
webbrowser.open`
```

Comment: Please include an [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `os` or [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to run the opera luncher with argument `--private`

somthing like this:

```
"C:\<path to opera folder>\Opera\launcher.exe" --private
```

Full code:

```
import subprocess


command = r'"C:\<path to opera folder>\Opera\launcher.exe" --private'
subprocess.Popen(command)
```

Comment: I tried this part of code  ` import os os.startfile(directory) -- private ` but did not work for me , im doing in pycharm